# How to Remove Border of Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I need to remove the Border of Carousel in Bootstrap here is my work:

```
.carousel-indicators .active{ background: #31708f; } 
.content{ margin-top:20px; } 
.adjust1{ float:left; width:100%; margin-bottom:0; } 
.adjust2{ margin:0; } 
.carousel-indicators li{ border :1px solid #ccc; } 
.carousel-control{ color:#31708f; width:5%; } 
.carousel-control:hover, 
.carousel-control:focus{ color:#31708f; } 
.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right { background-image: none; } 
.media-object{ margin:auto; margin-top:15%; } 
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { .media-object{ margin-top:0; } }
```

I'm trying to use  "border:0px" but it doesnt work 
Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ngb-carousel:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like bootstrap's CSS may be taking precedent over your custom CSS. To resolve this, try changing to 'border:0px !important', or be sure to load your custom css file before bootstrap's.